# Javascript not waiting for Promise to be resolved in a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

My js code needs to wait until ajax is finished to load the data.

```
if (district_search_value[0] == true) {
        var zone_search_value = checkZone(district_search_value[1], datas[i]['recipient_zone']);
        console.log(zone_search_value);
    }
```

The checkZone function :

```
   function checkZone(district_id, zone_name) {
    var value = [];
    value[0] = false;
    value[1] = 0;
    find_zones_from_district_id().then(function(data) {
        // Run this when your request was successful
        console.log(data);
        var zones = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(zones);
            for (zones_row = 0; zones_row < zones.length; zones_row++) {
                if (zone_name == zones[zones_row]['zone_name']) {
                    value[0] = true;
                    value[1] = zones[zones_row]['id'];
                }
            }
        return value;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Run this when promise was rejected via reject()
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

The main promise function :

```
function find_zones_from_district_id(district_id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxData_for_user.php',
            data: {import_excel_find_zones_from_district_id: 'district_id'},
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data) // Resolve promise and go to then()
            },
            error: function (err) {
                reject(err) // Reject the promise and go to catch()
            }
        });
    });

}
```

What is the reason behind javascript not waiting for promise to resolve ?
I've also tried the $.when in jquery but this also does not wait for ajax to load data.

Comment: Maybe use awaiter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sidenote `$.ajax()` returns a thenable, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a `Promise`

Comment: @STALER - I've tried with async await , but i was getting Promise {<pending>} instead of a value

Comment: @JaredSmith - thank you , that was insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need fixing, a third thing is optional

1. Wait for the promise to resolve before logging results using `.then()`

   ```
   if (district_search_value[0] == true) {
     checkZone(district_search_value[1], datas[I]['recipient_zone'])
     .then(zone_search_value => {
       console.log(zone_search_value);
     }
   }
   ```
2. checkZone must *return* the promise it gets from `find_zones_from_district_id`

   ```
   function checkZone(district_id, zone_name) {
     var value = [];
     value[0] = false;
     value[1] = 0;
     return find_zones_from_district_id().then(function(data) {
       // ...
   ```
3. As a commenter points out, there's no need to wrap the ajax call...

   ```
   function find_zones_from_district_id(district_id) {
     return $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'ajaxData_for_user.php',
       data: {import_excel_find_zones_from_district_id: 'district_id'} // did you want to pass a string here or district_id parameter?
     })
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've applied all three changes. Now i'm getting this error 
`find_zones_from_district_id(...).then(...).catch is not a function` in the checkZone function.
This is the code  `find_zones_from_district_id(district_id).then(function (data) { `

Comment: @iamneaz, I think this is due to jquery Ajax promises returning their own sort of promise.  Try `.fail(function(error) {})`. (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @iamneaz if you did the third step and directly returned the ajax call note the ajax() returns [jQuery's own structure jqxhr](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, not a true Promise it won't have a catch() method. Use `.fail()` instead or use the second argument to `then()` to set an error callback, eg `.then(function(){}, function(){/*error callback*/})`